# LINQ Inner joins

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xamarin, linq-to-sql

I created four model classes for my database in asp.net, the idea is to create a model for a Questionnaire, where the Questionnaire has multiple questions, and every question may have multiple answers , the answers have 3 types, multiple answers where the user can only select one answer, multiple answers where the user can select multiple answers and finally a text answer. A question only has only one answer type.

I have a Class ApiServices where I do the GETs to the tables, and I call the gets on the class inqueritogViewModel, what I want to do inner joins to the tables and then show the questions and answers on the designer class.

How can i do this?

Thanks.

```
 public class Inqueritog
{
    [Key]
    public int InqueritoId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreation { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpireDate { get; set; }
    public int ExpireIn { get; set; }

}


public class Answerg
{
    [Key]
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Answerv { get; set; }

    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

}


public class TypeAnswerg
{
    [Key]
    public int TypeAnswerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TypesAnswer { get; set; }

}

public class Questiong
{

    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public string Questionv { get; set; }

    public int InqueritoId { get; set; }

    public int TypeAnswerId { get; set; }

}
```

**Class ApiServices:**

```
public class ApiServices
{
    public async Task<bool> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string confirmPassword)
    {

        var model = new RegisterBindingModel
        {
            Email = email,
            Password = password,
            ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword
        };

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);

            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.58.30:17253/api/Account/Register", content);


            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }


    }



    public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
    {

        var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
    };
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://192.168.58.30:17253/Token");
        request.Content=new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var jwt = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Settings.LoginSucess = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        Settings.Username = username;

        JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jwt);

        var accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("access_token");
        Settings.AccessToken = accessToken;



        return accessToken;



    }
    public async Task<List<Inquerito>> GetinqueritosAsync(string acessToken1)
    {


        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", acessToken1);

        var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.58.30:17253/api/Inqueritoes");



        var inqueritos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Inquerito>>(json);



        return inqueritos;

    }

    public async Task<List<Inqueritog>> GetinqueritosgTaskAsync(string acessToken1)
    {


        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", acessToken1);

        var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.58.30:17253/api/Inqueritogs/");



        var inqueritos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Inqueritog>>(json);



        return inqueritos; 

    }
    public async Task<List<Questiong>> GetQuestionsTaskAsync(string acessToken1)
    {


        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", acessToken1);

        var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.58.30:17253/api/Questiongs");




        var questions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Questiong>>(json);



        return questions; 

    }

    public async Task<List<Answerg>> GetAnswerTaskAsync(string acessToken1)
    {


        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", acessToken1);

        var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.58.30:17253/api/Answergs");




        var Answers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Answerg>>(json);



        return Answers;

    }

    public async Task<List<TypeAnswerg>> GetTypeAnswerTaskAsync(string acessToken1)
    {


        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", acessToken1);

        var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.58.30:17253/api/TypeAnswergs");




        var TypeAnswers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TypeAnswerg>>(json);



        return TypeAnswers;

    }


}
```

**Class inqueritogViewModel:**

```
public class InqueritogViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
    public List<Inqueritog> _inqueritos;
    private List<Questiong> _questions1;
    private List<string> _inqueritosFinal;

    private List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvpList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    private List<Answerg> _answers;
    private List<TypeAnswerg> _typeAnswers;


    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    public List<Inqueritog> Inqueritos
    {
        get { return _inqueritos; }
        set
        {
            _inqueritos = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<string> inqueritos_Final
    {
        get { return _inqueritosFinal; }
        set
        {
            _inqueritosFinal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<TypeAnswerg> TypeAnswers
    {
        get { return _typeAnswers; }
        set
        {
            _typeAnswers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<Answerg> Answers
    {
        get { return _answers; }
        set
        {
            _answers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<Questiong> Questions
    {
        get { return _questions1; }
        set
        {
            _questions1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public ICommand GetinqueritoCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                AccessToken = Settings.AccessToken;

                Questions = await _apiServices.GetQuestionsTaskAsync(AccessToken);
                Inqueritos = await _apiServices.GetinqueritosgTaskAsync(AccessToken);
                Answers = await _apiServices.GetAnswerTaskAsync(AccessToken);
                TypeAnswers = await _apiServices.GetTypeAnswerTaskAsync(AccessToken);



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Design Questionnaire:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels;assembly=App"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Messier16.Forms.Controls;assembly=Messier16.Forms.Controls"
         xmlns:xfControls="clr-namespace:AsNum.XFControls;assembly=AsNum.XFControls"
         x:Class="App.ViewModels.InqueritoPage">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:InqueritogViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>
    <Button Command="{Binding GetinqueritoCommand}" Text="Aceder a Questionarios"></Button>

    <ListView x:Name="InqueritoView" ItemsSource="{Binding Inqueritos}" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="ListView_OnItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout >
                            <Label x:Name="Label1" Text="{Binding Pergunta}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <controls:Checkbox></controls:Checkbox>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Answer}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <controls:Checkbox></controls:Checkbox>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Answer1}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <controls:Checkbox></controls:Checkbox>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Answer2}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Use LINQ queries for such kind of requirements.

Comment: You have any examples?
thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins